# Printwriter creates empty files even after using printwriter.close

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I am using `PrintWriter` but it sometimes creates empty files.

I have also used `PrintWriter.close()` at the end but it still creates empty file sometimes.

**Code:**

```
StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
for (Iterator<String> i = fieldMap.values().iterator(); i.hasNext();) 
{
  String fieldValue = i.next();
  LOG.debug("Write information to outputfile:  fieldValue" + fieldValue);
  fileContent.append(fieldValue);
  if (i.hasNext())
    fileContent.append("~");
}

// Member errorMessage is only set in case of fatal error and might
// be appended without risk since in
// this case this content is only written to logger.
fileContent.append(errorMessage);
fileContent.append("\n");

PrintWriter docFileWriter = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
docFileWriter.write(fileContent.toString());
docFileWriter.close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - and format it so that it's readable. I would strongly encourage you to use the try-with-resources statement to avoid leaving writers open if an exception is thrown - and to avoid `PrintWriter` when you're not using any of its features. `BufferedWriter` would be fine here, and wouldn't suppress exceptions like `PrintWriter` does. I'd also suggest using `StandardCharsets` rather than naming the encoding. Or just use `Files.newBufferedWriter` which uses UTF-8 by default...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, your `fileName` is valid and your `fileContent`is not empty (debbuging with condition or add console-outputs).

To test the `PrintWriter` you can use this short example code:

```
PrintWriter docFileWriter = new PrintWriter("C:/temp/temp.txt", "UTF-8");
docFileWriter.write("Some special text: Aäç/)!é");
docFileWriter.close();
```

When your files are sometimes empty but exists, you should keep attention on the `fileContent` variable.